# Is there a way to have the previous column marked changed using .ne?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to show when there's been a change in the value in a column.  I'm using the `.ne` function.  I have the following code:

```
df['Changed'] = df['Column A'].ne(df['Column A'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
mouse_final_df_four.head(50)
```

here's a sample of the df

```
7   k403    
8   k403    
9   k403    
10  s185    
11  s185    
12  s185    
13  s185
```

here's a sample of what i'm looking to get back

```
7   k403    0
8   k403    0
9   k403    1
10  s185    0
11  s185    0
12  s185    0
```

which nicely creates a column "Changed" to track when I have a new value in Column A.  But rather than showing when I have a new value, I'd like the 1 to be in a previous row, indicating the end of the list of values in Column A.  How do I change my code to reflect the end rather than the beginning of the next one?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share sample input and expected output.

Comment: i went ahead and edited to show sample data!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `shift(-1)`

```
df['flag'] = df['Column A'].ne(df['Column A'].shift(-1).fillna(df['Column A'])).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Column A  flag
7      k403     0
8      k403     0
9      k403     1
10     s185     0
11     s185     0
12     s185     0
13     s185     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `shift` the values in opposite order: Use `shift(-1)`

```
df['Changed'] = df['Column A'].ne(df['Column A'].shift(-1)).astype(int)

In [1346]: df
Out[1346]: 
    Column A  Changed
7   k403        0
8   k403        0
9   k403        1
10  s185        0
11  s185        0
12  s185        0
13  s185        1
```

Comment: do you mean `ffill()` instead of `bfill`?

Comment: I meant `shift(-1)`.

Comment: Apparently I didn't ask for `shift(-1)` :-).

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Look at the last item in your output and OP's expected. in your code, `bfill` does nothing.

Comment: Yes, I removed that. Edited the answer. Thanks.